# How to save html5 video element with webkit-filter effect?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, getusermedia

I can save HTML5 video element to DataURL and it's working fine. But I have a problem when I add a -webkit-filter css rule to video element - the picture that I can take is without effect from -webkit-filter. 
My code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 860;
canvas.height = 640;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(this.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
canvas.style['-webkit-filter'] = 'blur(2px)';

var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); 
window.open(dataURI);
```

but it still no saving "blur" effect - only plain picture.

I will be very grateful if someone could help me :)

Comment: You can apply a blur to html5 canvas using [the StackBlur library](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html). Then your `.toDataURL` will be blurred.

Comment: Ok, but what with any other effect? For example grayscale, sepia, etc..?

Comment: Html5 canvas is not an image so the image filters will not work directly on canvas. These [compositing filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) are available natively in canvas. Alternatively, you can DIY by manipulating pixels. Alternatively, you can create an html img object using the dataURL as img.src and then apply webkit-filters to that img.

Comment: @markE please post you suggestion about creating img - I will accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an img element using `myNewImg.src=canvas.toDataURL()` and then apply filter(s) to that new img.

Here's example code and a Demo (view in Chrome Browser):

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/card.png";
function start(){
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  var filteredImg=new Image();
  filteredImg.id='filteredImg';
  filteredImg.onload=function(){
    document.body.appendChild(filteredImg);

  }
  filteredImg.src=canvas.toDataURL();

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
#filteredImg{ 
-webkit-filter: blur(3px);
-moz-filter: blur(3px);
-ms-filter: blur(3px);
-o-filter: blur(3px);
filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<h4>View in Chrome or FF. IE & Edge don't yet support filters</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I know it was in OP's comment, but CSS does consider the canvas as an image, and the `filter` should be applied to the canvas too : https://jsfiddle.net/pdbxmycb/

Comment: @Kaiido I didn't know that...thanks for the info! I guess that also explains why Chrome & FF will let you right-click-save-as a canvas just like an image. :-)